# Implicit conversion on this not kicking in

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

why is the implicit conversion on this only kicking in if this is explictly stated?

```
implicit class Foo(b: Bar) {
  def foo = 1
}

class Bag extends Bar {
  val bag = foo // does not work
  val bag = this.foo // does work
}
```

dero

Answer (score 4):

When you say `val bag = foo`, the compiler is going to look for a value within the scope named `foo`. If it can't find one, it will throw an error.

In order to trigger the implicit, you need to attempt to call the method `foo` an on object that doesn't have that method. In this case, `this` is that object. Only then will the compiler implicitly convert `this` to `Foo` in order to call `foo`.

The compiler isn't automatically going to try to expand `foo` into `this.foo`. What if `foo` isn't supposed to be a class member? What if it's a local variable? How can it possibly know what was intended?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine it expanded and that should answer your question:

```
val bag = new Foo(this).foo
```

If you simply call `foo`, the compiler isn't going to make the jump to throw `this` in front of it to kick off the implicit search. You need to supply the hint that `this` should be used and subsequently wrapped.